# Uploading a file via webapi using an azure website

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to upload a file using webapi hosted as an azure website. I'm getting a 400 bad request error.

Failed request tracing tells me that the module ManagedPipelineHandler is giving the 400 status with a notification of 128.

Googling suggests this is down to file size limits.

The `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` is successfully saving the file into a temp folder on azure, and I know the code "works on my machine" so I suspect it's a config issue (the files are under a meg at the moment)

I've tried changing the `maxRequestLength` to something quite high in the config but that hasn't resolved the issue, and I can't really see anything to change for webapi itself.

Any advice would be great!

Ta

Ross

Answer (score 0):

Avoid uploading files to local storage of the Azure Website. Instead, upload the file to centralized Azure blob storage.

Comment: The application I'm writing has to be used by both enterprises who trust "the cloud" and those who don't. I'd like to keep the code as similar as possible. The azure mvc site saves the file to sql azure storage currently, but eventually will save it into blob storage. For now I just need to make this work however.